# moongoose query array of objects of array using lodash or underscorejs

Tags: angularjs, mongoose, underscore.js, lodash

Here is an example of my data:

```
[
    {
        "_id": "54ff1f21592a15378825aa33",
        "timeline": "54fb49274e3e0c17271205d9",
        "name": "Ade Idowu",
        "first_name": "Ade",
        "last_name": "Idowu",
        "cohort": {
            "name": "Class III",
            "color": "#308cea"
        },
        "__v": 3,
        "tasks": [
            {
                "_id": "54ff2eb0a6299969a08f8797",
                "personName": "Ade Idowu",
                "projectName": "yec",
                "startDate": "2015-03-19T23:00:00.000Z",
                "endDate": "2015-03-06T23:00:00.000Z",
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "_id": "54ff1f21592a15378825aa33",
        "timeline": "54fb49274e3e0c17271205d9",
        "name": "Bola Idowu",
        "first_name": "Bola",
        "last_name": "Idowu",
        "cohort": {
            "name": "Class III",
            "color": "#308cea"
        },
        "__v": 3,
        "tasks": []
    }
]
```

I want to query `person.tasks` to display names of those whose tasks array is empty and those whose `tasks.endDate` has expired. I would appreciate using javascript or probably lodash.

Comment: When you say `tasks.endDate` has expired, do you mean _any_ tasks, or _all_ tasks for the given person?

Answer (score 1):

Use lodash _.filter(collection, predicate):

> Iterates over elements of collection, returning an array of all
>   elements predicate returns truthy for.

Predicate checks if iteree's task array is empty or the task endDate is smaller then the current time.

`.getTime()` returns the ms value of the date object so you can compare the two dates. This could be adjusted if you would like to filter by another granularity (ex. hours, days).

```
_.filter(dataObject, function(item){
  var now = new Date();
  return item.tasks.length == 0 || (newDate(item.tasks.endDate).getTime()  < now.getTime());
});
```

Comment: Good answer! However, generally answers are much more helpful if they include an explanation of what the code is intended to do, and why that solves the problem without introducing others.

Comment: Updated with explanation.

Comment: The approach was right. Thanks.
Aside the dataObject, the tasks is also an array of object, thus arise the need for filtering through it, then the date condition can be checked from the second filtering i.e ```(newDate(arg.endDate).getTime() < noe.getTime())```. Thanks